# WP8 HttpClient "Invalid Port Specified"

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to build an app on WP8 that will download json data from a webserver using httpclient from the NuGet package, but that content is not hosted on a standard port (85 is what is used).  When I try to download it I get "Invalid Port Specified".  I'm assuming this means it is restricted to 80, 8080, 443, or 8443 by default but I'm hoping there is some way to get it to work for a non-standard web port.  I have the same thing working in my Windows 8 metro app.  Any suggestions on how to fix it?  Just to state in advance, no I cannot change the port on the server side of things.

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(App.UserName, App.Password);
handler.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
handler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Error accessing server. " + response.StatusCode.ToString(), "Server access failure", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
    return "";
}
else
{
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the port information in the `url`.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.bob.com:85/endpoint.json");
```

Comment: I do have the port number included in the URL.  The service I need happens to be on port 85, but I can specify port 80 or 443 of a website and see that the string data is downloading.  It seems WP8 doesn't allow non-standard ports to be accessed, at least by default.

Comment: Turns out I had url encoding grabbing the / after the port number, so it was a dumb mistake.

Comment: Thanks for following up.